# Is a variable in anonymous runnable class always thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, interface, concurrency, runnable

I created a class UnSafeTask:

```
package com.threads;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class UnsafeTask implements Runnable {
    private Date startDate;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        startDate = new Date();
        System.out.printf("Starting Thread: %s : %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getId(), startDate);
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((int) Math.rint(Math.random() * 10));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.printf("Thread Finished: %s : %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getId(), startDate);
    }    
}
```

I used it in a class Core as below:

```
package com.threads;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Core {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UnsafeTask task = new UnsafeTask();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(task);
            thread.start();
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is as expected (the variable is shared by the threads). When I refactored Core as follows to use an anonymous runnable class:

```
package com.threads;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Core {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                Date startDate = new Date();

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startDate = new Date();
                    System.out.printf("Starting Thread: %s : %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getId(), startDate);
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((int) Math.rint(Math.random() * 10));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.printf("Thread Finished: %s : %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getId(), startDate);    
                }    
            });
            thread.start();
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the variable (startDate) is thread safe. Why is the variable thread safe in this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you have 1 instance of your Runnable (shared among all threads).  in your second example, you have 10 instances of your Runnable, 1 instance per Thread (no sharing, hence, thread-safe).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Thread safety does not depend on whether or not a class has a name. In the first case, you share an *instance* of a named class among all threads; you can easily do the same exact thing with your second, anonymous, class!

Moreover, you can share `final` variables declared in the outer scope among instances of an anonymous class. Even though the variable must be final, it does not mean that its instance would be *immutable*. In cases like that, anonymous classes would most certainly be non thread-safe.

So the answer from your title question is "no, not all anonymous classes are thread-safe". You need to explicitly design your class with thread safety in mind, regardless of whether it is named or not.

Answer (score 0):

A class being anonymous or not is irrelevant to thread safety.

An anonymous class is just like a regular class, except its source does not live in its own `.java` file (and a couple of other very minor things).

Answer (score 0):

Note that your second example is the same as a slight modification of the first:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Task object instantiation now inside for loop:
        UnsafeTask task = new UnsafeTask();   
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
```